# How to get an IntPtr to access the view of a MemoryMappedFile?

Tags: c#, memory-mapped-files, intptr

Is there a way to get a direct `IntPtr` to the data in a MemoryMappedFile?
I have large data block with high frequency change and I don't want to copy it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, not an IntPtr, that doesn't help you anyway.  You can get a `byte*`, you can cast it at will to access the actual data type.  And you can cast it to IntPtr if you have to.  Having to use the `unsafe` keyword is quite intentional.

Create a MemoryMappedViewAccessor to create the view on the MMF.  Then use the AcquirePointer() method of its SafeMemoryMappedViewHandle property to obtain the byte*.

A sample program that demonstrates the usage and shows various pointer shenanigans:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

class Program {
    static unsafe void Main(string[] args) {
        using (var mmf = System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles.MemoryMappedFile.CreateNew("test", 42))
        using (var view = mmf.CreateViewAccessor()) {
            byte* poke = null;
            view.SafeMemoryMappedViewHandle.AcquirePointer(ref poke);
            *(int*)poke = 0x12345678;
            Debug.Assert(*poke == 0x78);
            Debug.Assert(*(poke + 1) == 0x56);
            Debug.Assert(*(short*)poke == 0x5678);
            Debug.Assert(*((short*)poke + 1) == 0x1234);
            Debug.Assert(*(short*)(poke + 2) == 0x1234);
            IntPtr ipoke = (IntPtr)poke;
            Debug.Assert(Marshal.ReadInt32(ipoke) == 0x12345678);
            *(poke + 1) = 0xab;
            Debug.Assert(Marshal.ReadInt32(ipoke) == 0x1234ab78);
            view.SafeMemoryMappedViewHandle.ReleasePointer();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you should call `ReleasePointer()`, at least to be sure the GC doesn't free everything in the middle of the code.

Comment: And perhaps an abundant use of `using` for the same reason.

Comment: Well, as you wish.  Under protest, the OP should not be using the *using* statement.  This snippet just demonstrates usage.

Comment: I don't comprehend your comment... why shouldn't he use the `using`?

Comment: Thanks. If I need to use the pointer in another module, what is the risk if I wouldn't call "ReleasePointer"? (My SharedMemory is not closed until the program finishes). I guess each call I would get the same pointer?

Comment: Do you have any guarantee that the "other module" won't try to use the pointer after the mmf and the view are closed?  Simplest way to get that guarantee is to just not close them and leave it up to the finalizer.  Otherwise the reason I protested.

Comment: Note that if you call `CreateViewAccessor` with offset you must add that offset to the pointer from `AcquirePointer`, it is available as `view .PointerOffset`. The pointer from `AcquirePointer` refers to the beginning of the file regardless of the offset in `CreateViewAccessor`. Not sure if that is a bug or a feature, quite counterintuitive.